# MQ\Java - accessQueue() method - what should be the openOptions to avoid queue lock

Tags: java, queue, ibm-mq

I am writing a monitoring tool for a system which uses MQ websphere.
I want to check the queues depth by using the getCurrentDepth() method.
To be able to do so, I first need to access the queue using the function:

```
public MQQueue accessQueue(String queueName, int openOptions, 
                       String queueManagerName, 
                       String dynamicQueueName, 
                       String alternateUserId) 
          throws MQException;
```

My concern is that the call to getCurrentDepth() will **lock the specific queue** for some period of time, which is very bad for the monitored system.
My guess is that the **openOptions** are the solution but I haven't found any helpful information regarding these options accept for the [IBM WebSphere MQ API](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv6/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.mq.csqzaw.doc%2Fuj15100_.htm)

Any assistance will be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to inquire the current depth you will have to use the MQOO_INQUIRE open option.

However, that said, most monitoring tools would use PCF not MQINQ as the MQINQ verb is limited to things a business application, not a monitoring application would need. If all you want is the current depth, then fine, but if you intend to monitor anything else, you'll need to change tack.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. I've already found the solution and that was indeed it. The current depth is the only information that I need.